# #region throw warning with StyleCop.Analyzers

Tags: c#, stylecop

I'm using the [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) on a C# project.

When I use #region it throws a [Warning](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1124.md) that I want to avoid but I don't know how to handle this properly as I also want to get some sort of code-wrapper like the one given by the #region directive.

Any ideas on how to solve this without suppressing the warning?

Comment: Yes, do not use regions - not kidding. Regions are considered a code-smell at best and evil at worst - if your coding standards require regions I suggest you opt to change that - search the web for a plethora of examples why regions should not be used

Comment: If you want to use regions and StyleCop but not see the warning you're only option is to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regions, use partial classes. Extract your region into a new partial class.